# DynamoDB Parallel Scan not splitting results

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto, aws-lambda

I'm using the `Segment` and `TotalSegments` parameters to split my DynamoDB scan over multiple workers (as shown in the [Parallel Scan section](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html#QueryAndScanParallelScan) of the developer guide).

However, all of the results get returned to one worker. What could be the issue here? Is there perhaps an issue with how I've implemented threading?

```
import threading
import boto3

def scan_foo_table(foo, segment, total_segments):
    print 'Looking at segment ' + str(segment)
    session = boto3.session.Session()
    dynamoDbClient = session.client('dynamodb')
    response = dynamoDbClient.scan(
        TableName='FooTable',
        FilterExpression='bar=:bar',
        ExpressionAttributeValues={
            ':bar': {'S': bar}
        },
        Segment=segment,
        TotalSegments=total_segments,
    )
    print 'Segment ' + str(segment) + ' returned ' + str(len(response['Items'])) + ' items'

def create_threads(bar):
    thread_list = []
    total_threads = 3

    for i in range(total_threads):
        # Instantiate and store the thread
        thread = threading.Thread(target=scan_foo_table, args=(bar, i, total_threads))
        thread_list.append(thread)

    # Start threads
    for thread in thread_list:
        thread.start()

    # Block main thread until all threads are finished
    for thread in thread_list:
        thread.join()

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    create_threads('123')
```

Output:

```
Looking at segment 0
Looking at segment 1
Looking at segment 2
Segment 1 returned 0 items
Segment 2 returned 0 items
Segment 0 returned 10000 items
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing that jumps at me is the filter expression.

It is possible that the items that match your filter expression are located all in the first segment.

It is also worth noting that a parallel scan doesn't split the items, but it splits the key-space that is searched for items. Think of it as dividing a very large highway into multiple lanes.  It is possible le that most cars are in the fast lane and you won't see any cars in other lanes.

Though in this case it seems more likely that the filter expression is what is causing only one segment to return items.

Answer (score -1):

You're creating the DynamoDB session and client and sharing across all threads. If you look at the example, they don't do that. Try creating the session and client so each thread has its own, and this problem will likely go away.